# Select only numeric part of string column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a two columns.

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | Value  |
+--------+--------+
| XXXX1  | {5000} |
| XXXX2  | {136}  |
| XXXX3  | {2450} |
| XXXX4  | {229}  |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to extract only numeric part from 'value' column.

I have tried below:

```
select Number , substring(value from '[0-9]+') from table
```

But I get an error:
ERROR: function pg_catalog.substring(numeric[], unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Your second column is an array, just use `value[1]` instead

Comment: It works! Thanks!